# Add some parameter to EventHandler in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

By now I'm having this code

```
public void getRankingList(string country,string type)
    {            
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        string url = "......";
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += getRankingResult;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
private void getRankingResult(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        .........
    }
```

So now can I add some para to the downloadCompleted event ? something like:

```
private void getRankingResult(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e, string Para)
    {
        .........
    }
```

Comment: Use a lambda expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void getRankingList(string country,string type)
    {            
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
        string url = "......";
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) => 
        getRankingResult(sender, args, "para");
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

private void getRankingResult(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e, string Para)
{
    // .....
}
```

Comment: No problem, I didn't know about this approach until yesterday myself. It's changed the way I see lambda expressions (their use is seemingly a lot wider than a simple bit of `Where` LINQ)

Comment: Worked perfect :D I've seen "=>" sometime when use with sql but not really understand, now I knew it name is "lambda expression" :D Thanks a lot men :D

Answer (score 1):

If `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs` is not a sealed class then you can create a new class and inherit from it and add your additional `string Para` field to it.

Comment: And how you are going to convince the `WebClient` to use your newly inherited class when its going to fire the event?

Comment: @Maarten - wouldn't you just cast it inside the event handler?

Comment: @DeeMac No. You will get an `InvalidCastException` or something, since the event-arguments-object is not of the inherited type, but of type `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`. The event arguments of an eventhandler is just a simple object containing some data, so you still cannot cast an object to another type that it isn't.

Comment: Ahh of course, I wasn't seeing it from the point of what actually gets passed to the event handler.

Comment: @Maarten - are you saying you cannot cast the object to the inherited class (`as` and `is` or direct cast)?  This would work in other circumstances so why not with the event model?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh If you have `class A { }` and `class B: A { }` then the following would result in a cast exception `var a = new A(); var b = (B)a;` since A is not of type B, and that is what we are talking about. The `WebClient` creates an object of type `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`, and in your eventhandler you are going to cast it to an inherited type `InheritedDownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`. That is not going to work.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh And no, this (casting to an inherited type) would not work anywhere else either, if the actual object is not of the inherited type.

Comment: @Maarten. Agreed.  I thought the client had control of instantiating the equivalent of `B` instead of `A` but if as you say, `WebClient` creates the object then you are right. Cheers.  
PS: Should I delete my entire answer?